# ContentResolver Client App cannot find table from ContentProvider

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-contentprovider

Cannot really find an answer to this particular case. I'm trying to implement a really simple fetch of all the rows from my contentprovider app's already existing database and populate the rows in a listview.

My client gets the classic error

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: names (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM names
            at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:181)
            at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:137)
            at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:421)
            at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:478)
            at android.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground(CursorLoader.java:64)
            at com.example.user.myclient.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)
```

Here is the simple code in MyClient's main:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://map524.myfriends");
        Cursor c;
        CursorLoader cl = new CursorLoader(this, uri, null, null, null, null);
        c = cl.loadInBackground();

        String[] columns = new String[] {
            "Id", "name", "phone", "email"
        };

        int[] views = new int[] {
          R.id.namesId, R.id.names, R.id.phone, R.id.email
        };
        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.activity_main, c, columns, views);

        ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

The content provider's class simply executes a "SELECT * FROM names" which is the existing table in the database. This query works perfectly on the local app that contains the database file as the asset. **The error happens when I go ahead and run the content provider app, and then try to run my content resolver/client app on the same AVD**:

```
// MyDBProvider class
public class FriendsProvider extends ContentProvider {
    MySQLiteHelper dbHelper;

// ... Required blank methods all exist of course, but not implemented
 @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {
        // TODO: Implement this to initialize your content provider on startup.

        dbHelper = new MySQLiteHelper(getContext());
        return false;
    }
@Override
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
                        String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
        // TODO: Implement this to handle query requests from clients.
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

        return db.query("names", projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);
    }
```

And this code works just fine in the contentProvider's local app:

```
public class MySQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String TABLE_NAMES = "names";
    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "name";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "names.db";
    private static String DB_PATH = "";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE names (_id integer PRIMARY KEY, name text, phone text, email text);";
    private final Context mContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDataBase;

    public MySQLiteHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        DB_PATH = context.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).getPath();

        this.mContext = context;
    }

    public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
        //If database not exists copy it from the assets
        boolean mDataBaseExist = checkDataBase();
        if(!mDataBaseExist)
        {
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            try
            {
                //Copy the database from assets
                copyDataBase();
                Log.e("MySQLiteHelper", "createDatabase database created");
            }
            catch (IOException mIOException)
            {
                throw new Error("ErrorCopyingDataBase");
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean checkDataBase() {
        File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME);
        //Log.v("dbFile", dbFile + "   "+ dbFile.exists());
        return dbFile.exists();
    }

    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException
    {
        InputStream mInput = mContext.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
        OutputStream mOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        byte[] mBuffer = new byte[1024];
        int mLength;
        while ((mLength = mInput.read(mBuffer))>0)
        {
            mOutput.write(mBuffer, 0, mLength);
        }
        mOutput.flush();
        mOutput.close();
        mInput.close();
    }

    public boolean openDataBase() throws SQLException
    {
        String mPath = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
        mDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);
        return mDataBase != null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    }

    public Cursor fetchRows() {
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAMES;
        Cursor cursor = mDataBase.rawQuery(query, null);
        return cursor;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close()
    {
        if(mDataBase != null)
            mDataBase.close();
        super.close();
    }
```

Thanks in advance, as always.
    }

Comment: have you tried it on a real device?

Comment: Currently can't use one, unfortunately

Comment: Because the code looks fine (I have not tested it though), it might be an issue with the emulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the problem here is that my content provider logic ends up trying to access the SQLiteHelper instance directly, as opposed to using the Data Access Object/Database Adapter class logic that deals with it. My understanding is that trying to implement a raw query using the SQLiteHelper instance directly in this case is trying to query a table from a database in the file structure that doesn't have any tables.

My new working logic is as such:

```
// In the provider class instance
NamesDataSource dbHelper;

 @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {
        // TODO: Implement this to initialize your content provider on startup.
        dbHelper = new NamesDataSource(getContext());
        try {
            dbHelper.open();
        }
        catch (SQLException se) {
            se.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
                        String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
        // TODO: Implement this to handle query requests from clients.
        //return db.query("names", projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null,  sortOrder);
        return dbHelper.getRowsCursor();
    }
// ... rest of blank required implementation methods
}
```

The Data Access Object/Database Adapter Class:

```
public class NamesDataSource {
    private MySQLiteHelper dbHelper;

public NamesDataSource(Context context) {
        dbHelper = new MySQLiteHelper(context);
    }

public void open() throws SQLException {
        try {
            dbHelper.createDataBase();
        }
        catch (Exception ioe) {
            throw new Error("Unable to create database");
        }
        try {
            dbHelper.openDataBase();
        }
        catch(Exception se){
            se.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

public Cursor getRowsCursor() {
        return dbHelper.fetchRows();
    }
}
```

The SQLiteHelper class doesn't change its logic. The client app code now uses this logic to retrieve the query data:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://map524.myfriends");

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.d("CLIENT", "Starting");
        fetchAll();
    }

public void fetchAll() {
        Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(uri, null,null,null,null);

        String[] columns = new String[] {
                "_id", "name", "phone", "email"
        };

        int[] views = new int[] {
                R.id.namesId, R.id.names, R.id.phone, R.id.email
        };

        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.activity_main, c, columns, views);

        ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```